# Scrapy ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "import"

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the next directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── my_import
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── middlewares.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── spiders
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── spider1.py
│   │   ├── spider2.py
│   │   ├── spider3.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── test.py
├── requirements.txt
├── scrapy.cfg
```

I want to test a one method of spider1 with unittests.

**test.py**

```
import unittest
from spiders.spider1 import SpiderA


class TestResult(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_return(self):
        string1 = '1'
        string2 = '1st'
        item = SpiderA()
        self.assertEqual(item.get_result(string1), string1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But I received the error:

**`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_import'`**

However I am able to import **settings.py**, **items.py**, **pipelines.py** files in **test.py file**.

I think this is due to the reason I am importing class from **items.py** inside of **spider1.py** file and this caused this error.

Any ideas how I can overcome this issue?

Comment: try `from .spiders.spider1 import SpiderA`

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback of the error? There’s no `my_import` in your code, so the error must be in some other file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what u have to do is :

```
from products_spiders.spider1 import SpiderA
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed a bit description of question. But this also doesn't help.

Comment: I think u should also check another library [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which make testing easier than unittest, if u can switch.